# ELSA-Workflows how far can it goes?

Tags: .net, angularjs

Here is a bunch of questions about [ELSA](https://elsa-workflows.github.io/elsa-core/);

1- what is the difference between ELSA and workflow engine .NET?

2- Does Elsa easy to integrate with both .NET Core and AngularJS technologies?

3- Does the Activities in one single flow could be managed by different users?

## ELSA-WORKFLOWS

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party, but I'm learning about Elsa tight now, so...

1. I don't know honestly. Never used MS workflows. As far as I'm concerned, it's legacy thing right now, they don't even cared to move this thing to .NET 5 so I guess it's dead.
2. Elsa could easily expose REST API so any JS stack should be fine. About .NET Core - it's running on .NET 5 right now, integration is nice and quite easy. Elsa is designed so it could be run as standalone app or as part of .NET Core, do as you please.
3. This is something I still need to figure out, but it seems, that Elsa use  authentication and authorization from Microsoft. You can configure it on `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs`:

```cs
services
    .AddElsa(
        elsa =>
        {
            // other config
            elsa.Services
                .AddAuthenticationCore(auth =>
                {
                    // authentication rules
                })
                .AddAuthorizationCore(opts =>
                {
                    // authorization rules
                });
        })
    // other stuff, dashboard, activities etc
```